# GET http://localhost:5000/api/posts 404 (Not Found) error on the console after API call

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, compiler-errors

I have built a full-stack blog application with React Js & Node Js. Tried connecting the API with the client side but I get the (GET http://localhost:5000/api/posts 404 (Not Found))-404 not found error. I have tried several ways including adding my proxy in the json file, and also changing the axios.get("/posts/",+search) into axios.get("http://localhost...")

This is how I have designed my:

**Post Component**

```
import "./post.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"


function Post({ post }) {
  const PF = "localhost:5000/images/";
  return (
    <div className="post">
      {post.photo && <img className="postImg" src={PF + post.photo } alt="" />}
      <div className="postInfo">
        <div className="postCategorys">
          {post.categories.map((c) => (
            <span className="postCategory">{c.name}</span>
          ))}
        </div>
        <Link className="link" to={`/post/${post._id}`}>
          <span className="postTitle">{post.title}</span>
        </Link>
        <hr />
        <span className="postDate">{new Date(post.createdAt).toDateString()}</span>
      </div>
      <p className="postContent">{post.description}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Post;
```

**Posts Component**

```
import "./posts.css";
import Post from "../post/Post";

function Posts({posts}) {
  return (
    <div className="posts">
      {posts.map(p => (
        <Post post={p}/>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Posts;
```

**My Blog Page**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./blog.css";
import Footer from "../../components/footer/Footer";
import TopBar from '../../components/topbar/TopBar';
import Posts from "../../components/posts/Posts";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Blog = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  const {search} = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/posts"+ search)
      setPosts(res.data)
    }
    fetchPosts()
  }, [search]);
  
  console.log(posts);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="about-navigation">
        <TopBar />
      </div>
      <h2 className="blogTitle">Our Blog</h2>
      <div className="blogPost">
        <Posts posts={posts}/>
        
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}

export default Blog
```

Comment: Please include the Nodejs route

Comment: Check your API method, I think it might not be the 'GET'

Comment: **GET ALL POSTS**
`router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
 const username = req.query.user;
 const catName = req.query.cat;

 try {
  let posts;
  if(username) {
   posts = await Post.find ({username});
  } else if (catName) {
   posts = await Post.find({
    categories: {
     $in:[catName],
    }
   })
  } else {
   posts = Post.find();
  }
  return res.status(200).json(posts)
 } catch(err) {
  return res.status(500).json(err)
 }
});`           @MohammedSaber

Comment: Can you also show me the controller (if it exists) or the index.js part responsible for app routing?